# How do I install Windows Driver Kit (WDK) into Visual Studio 2017 Pro in order to program WinUSB?

Tags: .net, windows

I want to program WinUSB and need to add a Windows Driver > USB project but this isn't available in my File > New > Project ...

I am following Microsoft: Docs/
Windows Hardware/
Windows Drivers/
Device and Driver Technologies/
USB
article [Write a Windows desktop app based on the WinUSB template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-write-a-windows-desktop-app-that-communicates-with-a-usb-device)

Somewhere in the doc it said Visual Studio 2017 comes with Windows Driver Kit (WDK).  I could not find this to install in Visual Studio Installer.

I INSTALLED WDT as per emsimpson92 suggestion, but no USB project.

Here available projects now...
[image]

Comment: If you open the visual studio installer do you have the desktop development with C++ plugin installed?

Comment: Yes. I have that and Uni Win Plat, ASP.NET, Python, .NET desktop

Comment: Install the WDK from the link I posted and you can find it in the new project menu under Visual C++ > Windows Drivers > Applications > WinUSB Application (Universal)

Answer (score -1):

[The windows driver kit can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk)

As far as I know you will not be able to find it by searching for it in the visual studio installer.

Comment: Installed it, but no project for USB.  See screen shot above.

Comment: Select the applications subsection of Windows drivers. The list on the right side will change and you'll see it available. You have Windows Desktop selected in your screenshot. [Here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/4pvAHE5)

Comment: @DougNull I'm not sure if you're still having trouble with this, but in your updated picture you still haven't selected the right option on the navigation panel. Rather than Visual C++ > Windows Desktop, select Visual C++ > Windows Drivers > Applications and you will see WinUSB application on the right hand side.